# Nuclear Testing and Carbon Dating

Tags: radioactivity

Will the nuclear testing done during the past decades or if a nuclear war happened in the present day, affect the accuracy of carbon dating in the future? (Hypothetically, we haven't developed a better dating method)

I mean you could just adjust the dating to the amount of Carbon-14 if there will be a sudden change, but will the fossils found in around and near the blast sites be dated differently from the unaffected areas?

I'm sorry not really good in science, I don't know if this should be in Physics STEX and I might be wrong in my understandings. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The usual path to C14 is the N14(n,p)C14 reaction.  Most of the N14 will be in the air, so the C14 will disperse. One would have to run some numbers of total neutrons generated in an all-out exchange to determine the additional C14 generated above normal background.  And, as @nordmaj indicates below, the historic C14 concentrations are calibrated using, e.g., tree ring series.

Answer (score 1):

If the amount of extra C14 was unknown this might become a problem. If the change in atmospheric C14 was recorded and the records survive into the future, it would be easy to adjust the dates. At present we have good data on C14 concentration over time for various locations around the world. I don't know the spatial resolution though.